# ANGULAR - Property doesn't exist on type object

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular-cli

I've been following the book **'Angular2 From Theory To Practice'** and I've come across a custom directive that works perfectly on the *plnkr* provided by the book but when I try to compile it in `node.js` it gives me below error:

> a "Property 'over' does not exist on type 'Object'."

```
Here is the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/J1ovl0c6hvZE73nRS29o?p=preview
```

Here is "my" code:

```
    **app.module.ts**


    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { RolloverImageDirective } from './rollover.directive';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        RolloverImageDirective
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }



    **app.component.ts**
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
    }



    **app.component.html**
    <img [ccRollover]="{
       'initial':'https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=201',
       'over':'https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=202'
    }" />


**rollover.directive.ts**
    import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'img[ccRollover]'
})
export class RolloverImageDirective {
  @Input('ccRollover') config: Object = {
    'initial': 'https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=201',
    'over': ''
  };

  @HostBinding('src') private imagePath: string;

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.config.initial) {
      this.imagePath = this.config.initial;
    }
  }

  @HostListener('mouseover') onMouseOver() {
    this.imagePath = this.config.over;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseout') onMouseOut() {
    this.imagePath = this.config.initial;
  }
}
```

Am I missing something in the ts.config file or maybe a compiling option in node.js, that allows this code to be successfully compiled?

Comment: If you think it's not a duplicate please let me know. All you have to do is to change `@Input('ccRollover') config: Object` to `@Input('ccRollover') config: any` or pre-defined type.

Comment: your plunker is working without any issues

Comment: @echonax thanks, that fixed it, but why does the plnkr's compiler accept the Object type and node.js doesn't?

Comment: @user2983177 it's not about node.js your compiler is giving the typecheck error. Since plunker ignores these errors your plunker is working.